# FATAL EXCEPTION: main, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, chat

I am beginner at Android app development and I have created a chat app using Firebase database. I am using two Android phones to test the app, Android Samsung 4.4.2 API 19 and Samsung 5.0.1 API 21. The app used to work fine on both phones. I added some lines in the CharActivity for notification purpose, I ran the app, it worked fine on Android Samsung 4.4.2 API 19, but crashes on Samsung 5.0.1 API 21 at the lunch. So I **undo** all the changes I made until the point where my app was working fine on Samsung 5.0.1 API 21. But the surprise is it still crashes!

Now I am facing a problem with the  Samsung 5.0.1 API 21. Every time I run the app it crashes at the lunch, and here is the problem I get.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.maalialabdulhafith.nfc_mac, PID: 30357 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
```

Please note that my other Android Samsung 4.4.2 API 19 works fine and doesn't crash.

FriendsFragment Class (Where all my friends are listed)

```html
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mFriendsList;

    private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String mCurrent_user_id;

    private View mMainView;


    public FriendsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

        mFriendsList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);


        mFriendsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mMainView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(

                Friends.class,
                R.layout.users_single_layout,
                FriendsViewHolder.class,
                mFriendsDatabase


        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder friendsViewHolder, Friends friends, int i) {

                //friendsViewHolder.setDate(friends.getDate());

                final String list_user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

                mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        final String userStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString(); // I added this
                        String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {

                            String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                            friendsViewHolder.setUserOnline(userOnline);

                        }

                        friendsViewHolder.setName(userName);
                        friendsViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());
                        friendsViewHolder.setUserStatus(userStatus); //<== if you want to show status instead of date


                        friendsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Open Profile", "Send message"};

                                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                                builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                        //Click Event for each item.
                                        if(i == 0){

                                            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                            profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                            startActivity(profileIntent);

                                        }

                                        if(i == 1){

                                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                            startActivity(chatIntent);

                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                                builder.show();

                            }
                        });


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        };

        mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);


    }


    public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        /*public void setDate(String date){

            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(date);

        }*/

        //if you want to display the statuse instead of the date, activite this and comment setDate method

        public void setUserStatus(String status) {

            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(status);
        }


        public void setName(String name){

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);

        }

        public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){

            CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);

        }

        public void setUserOnline(String online_status) {

            ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_online_icon);

            if(online_status.equals("true")){

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }


    }


}
```

Chat Class

```html
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    // user id whom we want to chat with
    private String mChatUser;

    private DatabaseReference mRootRef;

    private TextView mTitleView;
    private TextView mLastSeenView;
    private CircleImageView mProfileImage;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String mCurrentUserId;

    private ImageButton mChatAddBtn;
    private ImageButton mChatSendBtn;
    private EditText mChatMessageView;

    private RecyclerView mMessagesList;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mRefreshLayout;  // For Pagination

    private final List<Messages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayout;
    private MessageAdapter mAdapter;


    // For Pagination
    private static final int TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD = 10;
    private int mCurrentPage = 1;
    private int itemPos = 0;
    private String mLastKey = "";
    private String mPrevKey = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat2);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        mChatUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
        String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(userName);

        // to display the image in the bar
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View action_bar_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_custom_bar, null);

        actionBar.setCustomView(action_bar_view);

        // ---- Custom Action bar Items ----

        mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_title);
        mLastSeenView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_seen);
        mProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(custom_bar_image);


        //mChatAddBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chat_add_btn);
        mChatSendBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chat_send_btn);
        mChatMessageView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_message_view);

        mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messagesList);

        mMessagesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
        mRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.message_swipe_layout); // pagenation
        mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        mMessagesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayout);

        mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        loadMessages();


        mTitleView.setText(userName);

        // showing last time was seen

        mRootRef.child("Users").child(mChatUser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                String online = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                if(online.equals("true")) {

                    mLastSeenView.setText("Online");

                } else {

                    GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();

                    long lastTime = Long.parseLong(online);

                    String lastSeenTime = getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(lastTime, getApplicationContext());

                    mLastSeenView.setText(lastSeenTime);

                }

                //CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_image);

                //Picasso.with(i).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);
                //Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);


            }




            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        mRootRef.child("Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(mChatUser)){

                    Map chatAddMap = new HashMap();
                    chatAddMap.put("seen", false);
                    chatAddMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                    Map chatUserMap = new HashMap();
                    chatUserMap.put("Chat/" + mCurrentUserId + "/" + mChatUser, chatAddMap);
                    chatUserMap.put("Chat/" + mChatUser + "/" + mCurrentUserId, chatAddMap);

                    mRootRef.updateChildren(chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                            if(databaseError != null){

                                Log.d("CHAT_LOG", databaseError.getMessage().toString());

                            }

                        }
                    });

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



        mChatSendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                sendMessage();



            }
        });


        // Swipe/Pull to Refresh for Android RecyclerView

        mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                mCurrentPage++;
                itemPos = 0;
                loadMoreMessages();

            }
        });


    }

// ------------------ LOAD More Messages ------------------



    private void loadMoreMessages() {

        DatabaseReference messageRef = mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser);
        Query messageQuery = messageRef.orderByKey().endAt(mLastKey).limitToLast(10);

        messageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                if (!mPrevKey.equals(messageKey)){

                    messagesList.add(itemPos++, message);

                } else{

                    mPrevKey=mLastKey;

                }

                if (itemPos == 1){
                    mLastKey = messageKey;
                }




                Log.d("TOTALKEYS", "Last Key: " + mLastKey + "| Prev Key: " + mPrevKey + "| Message Key: " + messageKey );

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                mLinearLayout.scrollToPositionWithOffset(10,0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

// ------------------ LOAD Messages ------------------

    private void loadMessages() {

        DatabaseReference messageRef = mRootRef.child("messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser);
        Query messageQuery = messageRef.limitToLast(mCurrentPage * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);

        messageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);

                itemPos++;
                if (itemPos == 1){

                    String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    mLastKey = messageKey;
                    mPrevKey = messageKey;
                }

                messagesList.add(message);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size () -1);

                mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void sendMessage() {


        String message = mChatMessageView.getText().toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){

            String current_user_ref = "messages/" + mCurrentUserId + "/" + mChatUser;
            String chat_user_ref = "messages/" + mChatUser + "/" + mCurrentUserId;

            DatabaseReference user_message_push = mRootRef.child("messages")
                    .child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).push();

            String push_id = user_message_push.getKey();

            Map messageMap = new HashMap();
            messageMap.put("message", message);
            messageMap.put("seen", false);
            messageMap.put("type", "text");
            messageMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            messageMap.put("from", mCurrentUserId);

            Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
            messageUserMap.put(current_user_ref + "/" + push_id, messageMap);
            messageUserMap.put(chat_user_ref + "/" + push_id, messageMap);

            mChatMessageView.setText("");

            mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                    if(databaseError != null){

                        Log.d("CHAT_LOG", databaseError.getMessage().toString());

                    }

                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

What doesn't make sense to me is, how does it run on one device and doesn't on other? I would appreciate a detailed answer. Thanks in advance!

Acknowledgment: I have learned this code from the amazing TVAC Studio on Youtube.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661747/firebaseauth-getcurrentuser-return-null-displayname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user is not signed-in.
Change your code to the following

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null && !firebaseUser.getUid().isEmpty()) {
    // all OK
} else {
    //  repeat the authentication process again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by tim4dev, you havent logged in using any specific user. If you havent created a user, go to the firebase console and allow a signup type. They are like email and password auth, phone number auth, anonymous, etc. Once you have enabled one of the options, you can sign up using the auth class and sign in / login afterwards. Once you login with a user account on a device, only then will the

```
mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

statement work and return a non-null id.

Hope it solves the problem.