# Firebase Authentication on Android Foreground service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase custom authentication on my Android app. When the user logs in, I generate a custom firebase token on my server and send it to the app. The app then uses this token to authenticate with Firebase.
However, after completing this authentication when I do

`FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();`

in a foreground service, I get null.

Is the firebase authentication done on activity not valid in a service?

Comment: take look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661747/firebaseauth-getcurrentuser-return-null-displayname this may helps you

Comment: I am not able to relate that question to my problem. It seems related to User's information not being present in the expected field. Can you please explain more on this?

Comment: It's impossible to see what's going wrong from rhat single line of code. The problem is likely in how you use it. Please have a look at [how to create a complete, minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).